# Cannot get object from queryset

Tags: python, django

Code below should substitute all `\[\[(.+)\]\]` matches in 'content' field of AD with src of ADResource where `(.+)` is alias

`[[Similac]]` → `media/banners/2011/07/24/ad1.gif`

`[[res]]` → `media/banners/2011/07/24/ad2.png`

It catches DoesNotExist exception on [[res]] or [[Similac]] and returns 'res' or 'Similac' strings.

```
ADResource table contents:
id   alias      src 
----------------------------------------------------
1    Similac    media/banners/2011/07/24/ad1.gif
2    res        media/banners/2011/07/24/ad2.png


class ADResource(models.Model):
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    src = models.FileField(upload_to="media/banners/%Y/%m/%d/")  

class AD(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=10000)

    def getResourceURL(object, object_alias):
        try:
            return ADResource.objects.all().get(alias="%s" % object_alias).src.url
        except ADResource.DoesNotExist:
            return object_alias

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.content = re.sub(r'\[\[(.+)\]\]', AD.getResourceURL(self, r'\1'), self.content)
        super(AD, self).save(**kwargs)
```

But this code is working and i get url of src field:

```
return ADResource.objects.all().get(alias='res').src.url
```

Comment: What's the point of `.get(alias="%s" % object_alias)`? Why not just `.get(alias=object_alias)`?

Comment: Also, the first parameter to a method is usually `self`, by a very strong convention. What's your reason for breaking that convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, stupid question, i'm getting not a string but regex object and my match was in first subgroup.

```
self.content = re.sub(r'\[\[(.+)\]\]', lambda m: ADResource.objects.all().get(alias=m.group(1)).src.url, self.content)
```